# How to check if child process is created successfully in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm trying to open a file using using Node JS child_process like below

```
var child_process =require('child_process');
var spawn = child_process.spawn;
var exePath='<exe's path>'
var filePath='<file path>'
var childProcess = spawn(exePath, [filePath]); 
childProcess.stdout.on('data', (res) => {
            console.log('in spawn data');
            console.log(res);
})
childProcess.stderr.on('data', (err) => {
            throw err;
});
```

The problem here is that my file is getting opened in the specified exe properly..but the callback is never called...I'm guessing its because after opening the file the exe doesn't returns any output it just opens the file.

Also if there is any error in the filename the error callback is also not firing

**Question**

1. How I would know that the process is created successfully.
2. Is there any event which I can hook to know the successful creation
   of this child process.
3. Why the error callback is not firing in case of error.

Comment: If you have a `pid` that means the process is running, check here https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid

Comment: you might need a childProcess.on('error') and/or childProcess.stdin.on('error').

Comment: @JuanPicado That link is now slightly broken. Try this one: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_pid

Answer (score 0):

As @JuanPicado says in the comments, to check that a child process has spawned correctly you can check the PID thereof. Here's an example:

```js
import child_process from 'child_process';
const subprocess = child_process.spawn("grep");
if(typeof subprocess.pid !== "number")
    throw new ErrorError: Failed to spawn subprocess.");
console.log("Spawned subprocess correctly!");
```

From my observations, `subprocess.pid` will be `undefined` if the child process was not spawned correctly. Test it by changing the process name to include a typo to see.